# How to pass command-line args to my application when it has replaced Explorer.exe

Tags: delphi, replace, explorer, windows-shell

I am using the techinque shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/108265/how-do-you-replace-the-logon-shell-with-iexplore) and in a number of other places to cause my application to launch at start-up in place of Explorer (and Metro in Windows 8!) by creating a registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

with `c:\xxxxx\MyApp.exe` as the argument.

This works fine but I also need to pass it some arguments. I've tried this by making my key value (for example) `"c:\xxxx\MyApp.exe" "arg1, arg2"` but it would appear that arguments are being taken as a possible second start-up program with the comma as a delimiter. Can anyone advise how to pass arguments to a shell substitute? I've also tried double quotes with the same effect. Is it actually possible to pass arguments in this way? Or must I create some kind of launcher app to do this indirectly? I really do want my app to be the only kid on the block....

BTW I'm using Windows 8.0 and my app is written in Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you'd use the parameters just like you would in a batch file:

```
 "C:\xxxxx\MyApp.exe" "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4" "%5"
```

In a batch (or the registry) the "%x" parameters have special meaning. They always mean "parameter X".

Comment: Thanks Ken, that does seem to work with one proviso - that comma is NOT allowed in any parameter - and this was what was causing my problem. My first parameter is "/ul=a,none" and this was getting parsed as simply "ul=a Removing a comma seems to allow arguments to work as you suggest. Thanks.